# java how compare function works

Tags: java, collections, set, treeset

I am trying to break the rule of set by allowing the same object to be twice (just for fun)

This is my code:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    public String firstName;

    public Person(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return 4;
    }
}

class customTreeSet<T extends Person> extends TreeSet<T> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

and I call it like this:

```
Set<Person> set = new customTreeSet<Person>();
        set.add(new Person("Forza"));
        set.add(new Person("Forza"));
        for (Person person : set) {
            System.out.println(person.firstName);
        }
```

what I am facing is that when i leave the return as `4`, my set contains two objects, but when i change it to `zero` my set contains one object.

i need to know the rule for the returning type specially that it is integer not boolean, if it was boolean, i will say that true means two objects are the same, false means not, but here it is an integer value not boolean.

thanks for your help

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T- tl;dr: it returns 0 for equal objects.

Comment: you need to cheat with the equals() and hashCode() methods. You also need to get out more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Comparable` interface is used to compare two objects and their order. [As per the Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-), the `compareTo` method should return `0` if the two objects are equal, any negative number if `this` object is "smaller" than the specified other, and any positive number if `this` object is "larger" than the specified other. What "smaller" and "larger" means is entirely dependent on what you're trying to model - for Strings, for example, "greater than" and "less than" refer to their alphabetic ordering, while for Integers it refers to their natural ordering.

In your case, by always returning `4`, you're claiming that 1) the objects are not equal, and 2) both objects are larger than the other (which doesn't really make sense semantically, but if it works for you, whatever).